# maven 1 fails when running test

Tags: java, maven

I've changed the junit version from 3.8 to 4.4 in the application use maven 1. For that I change the project.xml, now look like this:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
      <properties>
<scope>test</scope>
  </properties>
</dependency>
...
```

I add some tests using annotations like @Test or @Before and those tests run perfect in eclipse. When I try to run "maven test" in console I get the following output:

```
    test:compile:
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class1Test
[junit] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.721 sec
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class2Test
[junit] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 1.16 sec
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class3Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.538 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class3Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class4Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.565 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class4Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class5Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.565 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class5Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class6Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.691 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class6Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class7Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.549 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class7Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class8Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.708 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class8Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class9Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.643 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class9Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class10Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.668 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class10Test FAILED
[junit] Running com.myapp.Class11Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.644 sec
[junit] [ERROR] Test com.myapp.Class11Test FAILED
[echo]
       ==========================================================
         WARNING:  There were test failures!
       ==========================================================
```

The test files that fail have more than one test inside. Maven just doesn't see them. Also when I use maven in debug I see that it loads implicit junit 3.8.

That's why I think somehow the old junit jar is been used. I just don't know where or how to detect it.

Any help, advise, ray of light will be appreciated.

Comment: _maven 1_? this version is [pretty old](http://maven.apache.org/release-notes-all.html) - could you elaborate why you didn't migrate to 2.* or 3.* yet?

Answer (score 3):

Try finding out why its loading junit 3.8. You can use mvn dependency:tree and then based on the result exclude it specifically.

Comment: +1 for mvn dependency:tree from me, added that to my answer then saw you had posted it here so i'm upping your answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of the `<properties>` element with a scope having any meaning in the way you've used it, unless another plugin needed it. It looks like you've tried to force a Maven 2 concept into Maven 1.

You could try setting the `maven.test.classpath` property to help it pick up the JUnit JAR. I don't make any guarantees about this working - JUnit 4 was never supported in Maven 1.x, and Maven 1.x has not been actively developed for over 4 years now. As you'll see, all the other responders are answering with answers only relevant to Maven 2 - you should strongly consider updating your build.

Comment: I'm using the property as it's recommended in http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/using/bestpractices.html. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

try using the latest one (though it in itself probably won't fix your issue here), also use

```
mvn -X clean test
```

and include the stactrace in your original post.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can also look at the output produced by the following and [exclude](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) the junit 3.8 jar

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Add an adapter in your tests :
    /**
     * @return instance of this as Junit test case
     */
    public static junit.framework.Test suite ()
    {
        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(IntTestSpringCoherency.class);
    }
```

Taken from: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Can-maven-1-x-run-Junit-4-tests-td92773.html

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution/workaround:

```
public void AClassUnitTest {
public static junit.framework.Test suite ()
    {
        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(AClassUnitTest.class);
    } 


    @Test
    public method_income_expected(){
    ...
    }

}
```

Thanks!